# How to get an IP address from an HttpResponseMessage?

Tags: dotnet-httpclient

Can one get an IP address from an HttpResponseMessage when using HttpClient (in System.Net.Http)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to get an IP Address (presumably of the remote server) from only a HttpResponseMessage.

The HttpResponseMessage type does not expose such a property *and it does not contain any types which have this information*. This means that the request can't be answered, even with the use of reflection.

See the [reference source code for HttpResponseMessage.cs](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/net/System/Net/Http/HttpResponseMessage.cs).

Comment: any other way to do it ?